# Populating an MUI table with dynamic data (from an API) in Next.JS

Tags: arrays, json, object, visualization

I am trying to populate a Material UI table component with dynamic data in Next.JS. The table component requires two props: `columns` & `rows`. My columns are essentially question texts from an online survey, and my rows are the unique responses supplied by each respondent.
After extracting my `columns` and `rows` and passing them to my tabe component, I get the result shown in the image below: [MUI table after passing column and rows props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNZ8N.png)

**How do I correctly map the response fields to the appropriate question texts on the same row?
A solution would be very much apprecited.**

**Below is the structure of my data:**

```
[
{
        "form_template_id": "bd74554e-70fa-4b32-acb8-7c0c49154de5",
        "question_responses": [
            {
                "id": "9f79a167-b0c8-42c0-bad0-1a63e043c038",
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "response": "Stephen ",
                        "date": "2023-08-16T14:15:44.497507Z"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "What is your name?"
            }
        ],
        "question_name": "What is your name?"
    },
    {
        "form_template_id": "bd74554e-70fa-4b32-acb8-7c0c49154de5",
        "question_responses": [
            {
                "id": "081ff3ae-a10a-47d2-a0ea-13b1e7f46099",
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "response": "I am Stephen ",
                        "date": "2023-08-16T14:15:44.50291Z"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Tell me about yourself?"
            }
        ],
        "question_name": "Tell me about yourself?"
    },
    {
        "form_template_id": "bd74554e-70fa-4b32-acb8-7c0c49154de5",
        "question_responses": [
            {
                "id": "44c7cd24-d7ec-4956-9091-b2a7ee9c3636",
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "response": "Cold, Hot ",
                        "date": "2023-08-16T14:15:44.552108Z"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "How do you like your tea? Choose all that apply."
            }
        ],
        "question_name": "How do you like your tea? Choose all that apply."
    },
]
```

**This is my implementaion of extracting the column and row data:**

```
  const prepareTableColumns = (responses) => {
    let columns =
      [
        {
          id: 'serial',
          label: 'S/N',
          minWidth: 150,
        },

      ];

    for (let i = 0; i < responses?.length; i++) {
      const headerText = responses[i]['question_name'];

      columns.push({
        id: `"${headerText}"`,
        label: headerText,
        minWidth: 250,
      });


    }
    return columns;
  }


  const prepareRows = (responses) => {
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < responses?.length; i++) {
      const rowText = responses[i]['question_responses'][0]['responses'][0]['response'];
      const headerText = responses[i]['question_name'];

      const row = {
        serial: i + 1
      };
      row[`"${headerText}"`] = rowText;
      rows[i] = row;
    }
    return rows;
  }
```

I am able to get the right mapping but **unable** to display them on a single row.